# Magento 2 add content on the product page

Tags: magento2, frontend, product-page

I'm using Magento 2, and I'm trying to move some content on the product page, so basicly I want to move the **add to wishlist**, **add to compare** and **email to a friend** under the product image, cause now they are under the add to cart button. I've tryed to move some code from `addto.phtml` into the `gallery.phtml`, but is not working properly. What file should I edit to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep in default.xml file,

```
<move element="product.info.extrahint" destination="product.info.media" />
```

Comment: that works good , only thing is that now the buttons are inside the picture container ,  there is any way to have it under , so is not also surrounded by the image container's border ?

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: to add the content under the product image container  cause now looks like is inside , cause also the add to wishlist ecc are surrounded by the container border.. so I just want to put them outside..

Comment: How do I know what's the name of the element I want to move , and what's the name of the destination ?